# How to Change Connection String of Published Application

Tags: winforms, connection-string, sql-server-2014

I have published a windows form application with a certain sql connection string . for security reasons i should change the password of my sql server user wich is used in connection string.
I tried to change password in published path in config.exe file but program did not consider the changes in connection string. 
Is there any way to change connection string without publishing the program again?

Comment: How do you publish your application? Are you using ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1):

yes
   Open Publish Folder>then open Application File>then open next folder thats name of your projects > then open file your projectname.exe.config in Notepad then you change your connectiostring

Answer (score 0):

Here config.exe is a compile file you publish it again to make work

Comment: how can i publish just config file?